# How to import and use a jQuery library via Webpack?

Tags: jquery, webpack, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using VueJS with Webpack, and I'm trying to use [this jQuery tags input library](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput). Given its needs, I'm including jQuery as a global:

```css
// in webpack.config.js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery",
  "window.jQuery": "jquery",
  "jQuery.tagsinput": "bootstrap-tagsinput"
})

// in main JS
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

That all works, but the issue is being able to get this other library in. I can `require` it into the main JS file (`require('../node_modules/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js');`
) and that gets it into my vendor file, but it doesn't execute and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use `import-loader` somehow, or some shimming thing - something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got it working. Here's what I did:

1. In `webpack.config.js`:

   ```
   plugins : [
    // ...
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       jQuery: "jquery",
       "window.jQuery": "jquery",
       "jQuery.tagsinput": "bootstrap-tagsinput"
     })
   ]
   ```
2. In my main Javascript file:

   ```
   // other imports, etc.
   require('imports?$=jquery!../node_modules/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js');
   ```

Note that this requires the use of the `imports-loader`.

3. In my component:

   ```
   export default {
     // ...
     ready: function() {

         this.$watch('MY_MODEL', function(elt) {
             $('input[data-role=tagsinput]').tagsinput();
         });

     }
   }
   ```

Note that you need to manually apply `.tagsInput()` here. The `.$watch` is to make sure that the element is actually rendered on the page. If you just put the `.tagsinput()` call straight into `ready`, it won't fire because the element hasn't necessarily been added to the DOM. You can also rig up a solution using `window.requestAnimationFrame` if you need to.